Flink JDBC Sink performance and impact on Database
I have a FLink streaming application which reads from Kafka and Upserts to multiple table atomically using CTEs ( Each CTE has an INSERT..ON CONFLICT statement). For even 1000 records from Kafka Flink is taking around 3 minutes while the same when I do using a simple Stored Procedure in Postgres, is taking up only around 6 secs.
For 1000 records, Flink is causing a CPUUtilization of around 20% while with Stored Procedure, its very negligible at around 2-4%.
Why is this happening ?
Also, I observed that even if I give a Batch Size of 1000 in Flink, its executing only around 500 records ( Batch Size seems to have no effect at all) but If I reduce the batch Size to 5 or 10, then it seems to reflect and it takes longer time to consume records.
Im having all the services like Kafka, Flink run in local and Postgres in RDS
